# correct development flow when using vagrant and puppet

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, puppet, digital-ocean

I have done some googling however I couldn't quite find what I wanted. What I am trying to achieve is have a local, development staging and live all using vagrant and puppet/chef.

Now I could be totally wrong and missing something but could I for example on my local development have the provider as virtualbox then for staging / development and live use AWS or DigitalOcean as the provider ?

If I am totally wrong what is the correct process for letting puppet/chef manage all my environments, any links would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I could be totally wrong and missing something but could I for example on my local development have the provider as virtualbox then for staging / development and live use AWS or DigitalOcean as the provider ?

Yes, that's how it works. Note that the `Vagrantfile` would need to have the information for your multiple environments, or you can simply have multiple `Vagrantfile`s